# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Using the ratio test:
$$\frac{1}{3}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^{n+1})^{n+1}}{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}\right|$$

Without evaluating the limit, the numerator is greater then denominator and the series is divergent. Is there an easier method for checking the convergence of this sequence?

Comment: You've left out the $3^n$ term in the ratio test, which will affect your answer.

Comment: The plain Ratio Test does not give us the answer in this case. The problem is that the ratio bounces back and forth from less than $1$ to bigger than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Use Cauchy's root test.

Let , $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{n^3(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n)^n}{3^n}$. Then , $\displaystyle\lim_n \sup |a_n|^{1/n}=?$

Answer (score 2):

Try the squeeze theorem:
$$
0\leq n^3\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n}{3}\right)^n \leq n^3\left(\frac{2.5}{3}\right)^n = n^3 c^n
$$
for $c = \frac{5}{6} \in (0, 1)$.